# Updating an entity object out of context requires 3 calls?

Tags: linq

Scenario:
I query for a record in a database using linq to entities.  So I open a data context, do my linq query, and pass the returned object off to my business logic layer / presentation layer.

Item gets updated from the presentation layer and a save event occurs and I pass the entity back to the bll/dal.

In my dal, I have to open up a new context, do a linq query to RE-select the object I want to update, update the returned record using my passed in entity, and then "SaveChanges()".

Am I doing this right?  It seems if I had used ADO I would have only had to make 2 database calls...the initial select and the update.  Now I have to do 3 calls (2 selects and 1 update) ?  Seems inefficient.  Comments? I hope they improve this in future versions because this could be a big downfall in high performance apps...

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using 'SaveChanges', I'm assuming you're using Entity Framework.  If that's true, you should be able to just attach your returned entity.

Indeed, this is how WCF RIA Services works, and they even wrap it up in an AttachAsModified extension method for you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff423414(VS.91).aspx